# MySQL query time vastly different on two different machines

Tags: mysql

This is driving me nuts.

I have the exact same database on two different machines, one Arch and one Debian. I'm running a query on the table below:

```
describe wellness;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra              |    
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| wellness_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| people_id    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| time_checked | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| check_type   | varchar(1)  | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| username     | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| return_date  | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| seen_by      | varchar(16) | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and the query:

```
mysql> explain select * from wellness         where wellness_id in (                 select max(wellness_id) from wellness group by people_id) and time_checked < (now() - interval 48 hour);
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | type  | possible_keys    | key           | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | wellness | ALL   | time_checked_key | NULL          | NULL    | NULL | 62546 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wellness | index | NULL             | people_id_key | 4       | NULL |   231 | Using index |
+----+--------------------+----------+-------+------------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

On my Debian server, where I'm migrating the application that uses this database, the query takes 7 minutes to run. On my Arch server, it takes less than a second. The weird thing is, the EXPLAIN is different on my Arch box, where I grabbed the SQL data from in the first place:

```
MariaDB [redacted]> explain select * from wellness         where wellness_id in (                 select max(wellness_id) from wellness group by people_id) and time_checked < (now() - interval 48 hour);
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys            | key           | key_len | ref                          | rows | Extra                    |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | ALL    | distinct_key             | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                         |  221 |                          |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | wellness    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,time_checked_key | PRIMARY       | 4       | <subquery2>.max(wellness_id) |    1 | Using where              |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | wellness    | range  | NULL                     | people_id_key | 4       | NULL                         |  221 | Using index for group-by |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+--------------------------+---------------+---------+------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any thoughts on what I need to adjust to get this working properly? As far as I can tell the Apache and PHP settings are the exact same on both servers, so I feel this is likely a database issue.

Comment: The new server does not collect optimizer statitics yet?

Comment: PM 77-1 is a great start. Also are your client MySQL versions identical? Is one using ODBC? My gut is that there's something different in your PHP set up rather than MySQL details. 7 minutes is ... well basically forever.

Comment: JimmyNJ - I'm not sure what the optimizer statistic PM 77-1 mentioned is, but I ran the below from Bernd with no results. However, your comment made me realize Debian has MySQL while Arch has MariaDB. I installed MariaDB on the Debian server and it worked. Stupid mistakes ;) Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

compare the output from

```
show variables LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

and verify the settings in your my.cnf.

also if you dump the database from one server and import it into the other, the datafile are not identical. the internal order of the row can be different.

you can also run this for your table to update the optimizer statistic

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```